# Incorporate badge feature on CMS

Tags: content-management-system, umbraco, badge

I am wondering if there is an easy way to incorporate the nifty "badge" feature of StackExchange to normal CMS, such as Umbraco. Ideally, I'd rather have a plugin with some basic XML editing or even box-ticking, or simple [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166465/woot-badge-like-in-php), but I can't divert much development time into a "nifty" feature for an internal tool.

[Someone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522943/best-way-to-store-badge-criteria) suggested programming an event system, eventually [storing rules in a DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049233/database-architecture-for-badge-system-arbitrary-criteria-mysql-php), in a [nice layered architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314412/designing-a-badge-system-where-to-fire-business-logic-in-code-or-stored-procedu), so I think there must be some tool already lying around somewhere ;)

Does anyone have a suggestion? Thanks XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I have found these tools: http://www.radcodes.com/products/plugins/socialengine-badge-plugin/ by the company RadCodes, and http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/achievements/ for the WordPress system. So there are some plugins out.

It seems there is none for Umbraco, so it would require some coding to implement, which is not going to fit in the company's schedule.

Answer (score 1):

BigDoor (bigdoor.com) seems pretty promising and is a nice free alternative to the spendy Badgeville. They have libraries for many languages, including C#. It may be possible to work it into Umbraco. I actually found this post looking for someone who had done just that. Let me know if you've come up with a solution.